# Visual studio 2013 build fails when Application Insights enabled

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, azure-application-insights

I have create an ASP.NET MVC5 application (with Application Insights enabled) and got it working with Git and Visual Studio Online. When I do a build it fails with the following error:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (3951): Could not copy the file "C:\a\src\packages\Microsoft.Diagnostics.Instrumentation.Extensions.Intercept.0.12.0-build02810\lib\native\x64\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensions.Intercept_x64.dll" because it was not found.`

Answer (score 1):

Reply from Microsoft is this issue should be fixed in the next version. Or try this workaround: add this to your proj file

```
<ItemGroup>

    <None Include="[Specify path to get to packages like:..\..\packages]\Microsoft.Diagnostics.Instrumentation.Extensions.Intercept.0.12.0-[SpecifyCorrectBuildNumber]\lib\native\x86\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensions.Intercept_x86.dll">

     < CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>

    </None>

    <None Include="="[Specify path to get to packages like:..\..\packages]\Microsoft.Diagnostics.Instrumentation.Extensions.Intercept.0.12.0-[SpecifyCorrectBuildNumber]\lib\native\x64\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensions.Intercept_x64.dll">

     < CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>

   </None>

  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me, still get the same error event though I see the .dll's in the bin folder. I've also tried adding the bin folder to the path to see if that helped but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've resolved this; take a look at the answer I posted here :

[Exception running application when adding insights to application using Application Insights Status Monitor Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27428492/exception-running-application-when-adding-insights-to-application-using-applicat)